# Android gestures: Scroll vs Fling

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and I am trying to learn how to animate gestures. Looking through the docs about how to detect gestures I saw there are two different gestures that are related to swipes: fling and scroll. Can anyone explain to me what is the difference between these two?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843671/android-swipe-vs-fling

Comment: Not really. That refers to swipe, not scroll