# How to make a button execute when we swipe over it ? (In android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, piano

I am trying to make a button that will execute when we swipe over it. (using java in android studio).
just like we can do it on the keys of a piano app.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking to implement the onFling() method:

- Drag: Fine gesture, slower, more controlled, typically has an
  on-screen target
- Swipe: Gross gesture, faster, typically has no
  on-screen target
- Fling: Gross gesture, with no on-screen target

[(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843671/android-swipe-vs-fling)

This might also be of some help to you:
[Swipe listeners in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975963/swipe-listeners-in-android)